# JSF internationalization Parameterized Messages with CSS and HTML tags

Tags: css, jsf, internationalization, parameterized

I'd like to know if it is possible to apply CSS and HTML tags to a part of the message or just to the parameter. The internationalization is working fine, but I`d like to know if this is possible without having two strings like #{strings.close}< b style="...">#{string.closeGood}< /b>.

1) I have in one place in my code value="#{strings.close}"
and in the strings.proprieties I have close = Close the page for good!

I`d like to know if you can apply a style of CSS to "the page" in the string above (for example) and for example a < br />

2) If I have

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{strings.verifyYourSelf}" >
                        <f:param value="#{testsBean.verifyNo}" />   
                    </h:outputFormat>
```

strings.properties I have verifyYourSelf = Verify if {0} is good. I`d like to know if it is possible to apply a style to the parameter and a < br />.

Have a nice day and good further coding! ;)